# gtk _get_type() function implementation

Tags: gtk, glib, gtk3, gobject

I just started learning GTK. I was going through source code of gtk+3.0.0, I found implementation of `_get_type()` methods for some gtk object types but some do not have an implementation of this method e.g `GtkRange`. Is there any reason for this? As far I understood from GObject Reference Manual, `_get_type()` method registers object type in type system.

Comment: Every widget should have a `_get_type()` function, either explicitely coded or implicitely defined by `G_DEFINE_TYPE` and derived macros: http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#G-DEFINE-TYPE:CAPS

Comment: @ntd I did not know about different types of macros .. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

the `get_type()` function is needed for all types registered as a GType. GObject (the library) provides convenience macros to generate the correct `get_type()` function implementation taking into account things like thread-safe initialization, or dynamic type registration.

the macro that is used for GObject (the type) subclasses is `G_DEFINE_TYPE()`, but inside GTK+ you will also find `G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_CODE()`, used generally when the type also implements interfaces; `G_DEFINE_ABSTRACT_TYPE()` and `G_DEFINE_ABSTRACT_TYPE_WITH_CODE()`, used for abstract types; and, more recently, `G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE()` and `G_DEFINE_ABSTRACT_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE()`, which define GObject subclasses with private data, avoiding the call to `g_type_class_add_private()` inside the class initialization function.

boxed types (GType wrappers around Plain Old Structures) also have `G_DEFINE_BOXED_TYPE()`, and interface types have `G_DEFINE_INTERFACE()`.

more information is available in the API reference for GObject:

https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.DEFINE_TYPE.html